# Alamofire 5: Value of type 'Result<Data, AFError>' has no member 'value'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Is the a new error in Alamofire 5? as this wasn't running into bugs last time. Below are the code which are done. Anyone who used Alamofire facing this?

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class MyAppService {
static let shared = MyAppService()
let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000"

private init() { }

func getCurrentUser(_ completion: @escaping (SomeRequest?) -> ()) {
    let path = "/somePath"
    AF.request("\(url)\(path)").responseData { response in
        if let data = response.result.value { //error shown here (Value of type 'Result<Data, AFError>' has no member 'value')
            let contact = try? SomeRequest(protobuf: data)
            completion(contact)
        }
        completion(nil)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to extract the `result` value as below,

```
func getCurrentUser(_ completion: @escaping (SomeRequest?) -> ()) {
    let path = "/somePath"
    AF.request("\(url)\(path)").responseData { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(String(data: value, encoding: .utf8)!)
            completion(try? SomeRequest(protobuf: value))
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is that SomeRequest?   @Kamran

Comment: @GulsanBorbhuiya `SomeRequest` is just the type of the object expected from the completion.