# AFError Alamofire 5 when parsing JSON

Tags: swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I just recently started working on an old iOS project that has AlamoFire 4.3 installed. I upgraded to 5 for security reasons. I'm not particularly familiar with the changes in Alamofire 5. When parsing a value from JSON, in this particular case a response message, I get an error `Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'`.

**Here's the request:**

```
AF.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
    {
        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)
        
        // Result code goes here...
        
    }
```

**Here's the code I'm getting an error on (Result code goes here...):**

```
if let result = response.result.value {
    let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
    self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
}
```

The key or "message" is the response code. This works well without any errors in Alamofire 4.3. Any suggestions on what I would need to make this work in version 5? [I've looked around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58177841/alamofire-5-value-of-type-resultdata-aferror-has-no-member-value) and I'm certain I need to extract `result`. Not really sure how I would do that though...

Comment: Have you ever considered learning how to unwrap optional values?

Comment: I have not. But would be interested in learning.

Comment: Except @ElTomato suggestion you can cast or change `AFError?` with `Error?`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than *looking around* the most nearby way is to **inspect** the type.

**⌥-click on `result`**. You will see

[image]

then click on `Result` to go to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result).

The `Result` type has two cases with associated types, a `success` and `error` case. So `switch` on `result` to handle both cases

```
switch response.result {
    case .success(let result): print(result)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
}
```

On the documentation site there are even further links to examples how to use `Result`.

Another valuable source is [Usage.md](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md), the detailed description how to use Alamofire.

Notes:

- Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift.
- Don't use `value(forKey` unless you mean KVC (you don't).
- Force unwrapping an optional to an optional (`as! String?`) is pointless.